# Express.js and Sequelize: does not define models

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am developing small app using express.js and sequelize.
Now I have a problem. I go with [this tutorial](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/#a-minimal-express-application) and stucked.

I am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
```

for

```
router.get('/news', function (req, res, next) {
  models.Article.findAll().then(function(article) {
    res.json(article);
  });
});
```

My model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Article = sequelize.define('Article', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return Article;
};
```

I host project by [github](https://github.com/skad0/shedule_api), any code you can see there.

Thanks for your help.

**UPD:** Added [console.log(models)](http://pastebin.com/PpEgg4Vn) to route /news.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(models)` into `/news` router and show it for me?

Comment: I have updated post with console.log that you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in `models/index.js`. In there you have:

```
...
.filter(function(file) {
  return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
})
...
```

This excludes all files which end in `.js`. Changing the final condition to `file.slice(-3) === '.js'` means that article.js is not filtered out. Article is defined in article.js.

To debug this I added the following line to your router function for `GET /news`:

```
console.log('KEYS TO models: ' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(models)));
```

This showed me that the only members of models were sequelize and Sequelize:

Comment: Thanks, you post it while I was writing similar solution. You're ahead of me for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to naming conventions, because Sequelize adds plural to models name. Good practice is to use plural names in your models definition so you're not tricked by that later in your code.

Try changing Article to Articles in your code and your model declaration.

Comment: Problem still there :-( But thx for answer and advice of good practice.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, I found that default models/index.js has an error.
When it iterate through files in models folder, there is an condition in filter

```
(file.slice(-3) !== '.js')
```

This will return false if file **has** an .js extension, that uncorrect.
Fix it to

```
(file.slice(-3) === '.js')
```

and it will work. Good luck!

Full correct construction:

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```